# Typeerror when trying to use getContext('2d') from canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive, html5-video

Why am I getting a type error when I try to `getContext` on my `el.canvas` Obj
html:

```
//created a directive called canvas-video-map
<div id="video-to-canvas" canvas-video-map>

  <video id="menu-video" loop autoplay video-loader preload="auto">
    <source src="../../images/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <canvas id='menu-canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('canvasVideoMap', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        //findes and maps the element children (video and canvas)
        var el = {
            video:    element.find('video'),
            canvas:   element.find('canvas')
        };
        console.log(el.canvas);
         // Type error is from here when i try to getContext
        var context = el.canvas.getContext('2d');




    }, false);
  };
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.find('canvas')
```

returns an array. Use

```
el.canvas[0].getContext('2d')
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to give like this

```
var context = el.canvas[0].getContext('2d');
```